# iTunes Connect Timezone?

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes-store

Our iPhone Application is set to the United States store.

Does anyone know what time period apple uses for this store (or any of them) for a full day? e.g. is it from 2400-2359 of the same day or 0600 of the 1st - 0600 of the 2nd?

Any ideas?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 15):

From [iTunes Connect - App Store Sales and Trends Guide](http://help.apple.com/itc/appssalesandtrends/#/itc37a18bcbf):

> **Time zone:** Reports are based on Pacific Standard Time (PST). A day includes transactions that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM PST.

Comment: 2023 here. Note they've corrected it to "Pacific Time (PT)" so that can be either standard or daylight time depending on the date.