# iTunes connect timezone confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

After reading the itunes connect FAQ im still confused on the following scenarios

1)Price changes

If I schedule a price change at 12am on monday, will all countries app stores have to wait till 12am Monday on their local time for the price change? Or will all the countries stores change price at the same instance when the itunes connect site hits 12am Monday?

2) Sales and Trends

Im in Australia and its 7th August here and in Itunes connect its 6th August. Sales and Trends just uploaded a daily report for 5th August. Now will that report show Australia's 5th August Report or will it show Australia's 6th August Report?

Answer (score 8):

From my observations:

1) I scheduled a price change at 12am monday EST (Australian time, Eastern Standard Time). The price changed at 12am EST on the Australian App Store and changed about 12pm EST on the USA App Store.

So you have to wait until it reaches the same time in all stores timezones, i.e. the App will show the scheduled price change at 12am in each country depending on their timezone.

2) The app was released 5th August iTunesConnect time (6th August EST). My friends and I downloaded it from the Australian App Store when released. I looked at 5th August report and saw no downloads from Australia, only from the USA.
So it showed data for 5th August EST which is no downloads because the app was not available in Australia on the 5th but the 6th.

Comment: i was thinking about time travel while posting. anyway i think i good feel of how the itunes timing works now

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. It would be fair to mark this as the answer, rather than the first response, which links to documentation about iTunes' reporting system, not their price schedules.

Comment: Hi, this is really helpful. I would like to know when you said the app was released at "2)", whether it was released manually or scheduled. I understand it was manually changed and I'd like you to introduce it to your answer, since it would make it complete.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer, @valmo, so it helps people in finding the most useful information.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this makes things clearer

Found this info here: [iTunes Connect Timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080785/itunes-connect-timezone)

From iTunes Connect - http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

**What is a Day?**

12:00:00 AM to 11:59:59 PM in the time zone used for that territory (refer to table below).

**What is a Week?**

Monday 12:00 AM to Sunday 11:59 PM

**What time is the report date based on?**

Territory: Time Zone
US, Canada, Latin America: Paciﬁc Standard Time (PST)
Europe, Middle East, Africa, Asia Paciﬁc: Central Europe Time (CET)
Japan: Japan Standard Time (JST)
Australia, New Zealand: Western Standard Time (WST)

**When are reports available?**

Reports are generated after the close of business in the ﬁnal time zone (which is PST). As such, reports are generally available by 8:00 AM PST for the prior day.

Comment: yeh i read that already but it didnt make it any clearer for my scenarios. =(